# What is the identity element for the subgroup $H=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q},\text{$a$ and $b$ are not both zero}\}$ of the group $\mathbb{R}^*$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, rational-numbers

For the subgroup $H=\left \{a+b\sqrt{2} : a,b\in \mathbb{Q},\text{ $a$ and $b$ are not both zero}\right \}$ of the group $\mathbb{R}^{*}$, what is its identity element? I know it must be $1$ since that is the identity element for $\mathbb{R}^{*}$. I am not sure how to make $a+b\sqrt{2}=1$. Any ideas?

My idea is that since it says "not both zero", one of them can be zero, and so $b = 0$ and $a = 1$?

Comment: The identity element of a subgroup must be the same as the identity element of the group.

Comment: That's quite right.

Comment: The definition of $H$ has a wrong condition which is too restrictive. You should relax it to $a,b\in\mathbf {Q}$ and either $a$ or $b$ non-zero.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: @Colescu Sorry, I did not copy straight from the textbook. I changed the definition of $H$. It is actually said "$a$ and $b$ are not both zero". Does that mean one of them can be zero?

Comment: A group is a set plus a law, do we have to guess it is the multiplicative group ? $\mathbb R^*$ is $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, is that what you meant ? Or did you mean $(\mathbb R,\times)$ or $(\mathbb R^*,\times)$.

Comment: You've got it. Taking a=1, b=0, you get the number 1, which is of course the multiplicative identity.

Comment: Actually undo my proposed edit. I did not read the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $a+b\sqrt2=1$, you can derive it: if $b \neq 0$, then $\sqrt2=\frac{1-a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$, which is absurd. Hence $b=0$ and $a=1$.